# navbar с большим количеством элементов

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap4

Есть навбар:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли средствами html/css сделать, чтобы при уменьшении размеров появлялся скролл в `ul`??  В данный момент просто вылазит за пределы

код:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light navbar-expand-md" style="background-color:#f2f3f4;">
        <a class="navbar-brand py-0" href="/">
            <i class="fab fa-accusoft" style="font-size: 170%"></i>
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse justify-content-start collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="listSupportedContent">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-1 text-center" href="/Home/Index">
                        <i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size: 125%"></i><br>
                        Главная
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-1 text-center" href="/User/Users">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-friends" style="font-size: 125%"></i><br>
                        Пользователи
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-1 text-center" href="/Discount/Discounts">
                        <i class="fas fa-compact-disc" style="font-size: 125%"></i><br>
                        Скидки
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-1 text-center" href="/Product/Products">
                        <i class="fab fa-product-hunt" style="font-size: 125%"></i><br>
                        Товары
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-1 text-center" href="/User/Users">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-friends" style="font-size: 125%"></i><br>
                        Пользователи
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-1 text-center" href="/Discount/Discounts">
                        <i class="fas fa-compact-disc" style="font-size: 125%"></i><br>
                        Скидки
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-1 text-center" href="/Product/Products">
                        <i class="fab fa-product-hunt" style="font-size: 125%"></i><br>
                        Товары
                    </a>
                </li>


                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-1 text-center" href="/User/Users">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-friends" style="font-size: 125%"></i><br>
                        Пользователи
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-1 text-center" href="/Discount/Discounts">
                        <i class="fas fa-compact-disc" style="font-size: 125%"></i><br>
                        Скидки
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-1 text-center" href="/Product/Products">
                        <i class="fab fa-product-hunt" style="font-size: 125%"></i><br>
                        Товары
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-1 text-center" href="/User/Users">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-friends" style="font-size: 125%"></i><br>
                        Пользователи
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-1 text-center" href="/Discount/Discounts">
                        <i class="fas fa-compact-disc" style="font-size: 125%"></i><br>
                        Скидки
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-1 text-center" href="/Product/Products">
                        <i class="fab fa-product-hunt" style="font-size: 125%"></i><br>
                        Товары
                    </a>
                </li>



            </ul>

            <form class="nav-item form-inline" id="formSearch">
                <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" style="display: none" name="search">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link" onclick="$('#formSearch').find('[type=\'search\']').toggle();">
                    <i class="fa fa-search" style="font-size: 140%"></i>
                </a>
            </form>


            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownUser">
                @*<a class=*@

                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownUser" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fas fa-user" style="font-size: 140%"></i>
                        </a>"nav-link " href="/User/Card?email=admin@admin.com">
                        <i class="fas fa-cog mr-2"></i>admin@admin.com
                        </a>

                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

                        <a class="nav-link " href="/User/LogOff">
                            <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt mr-2"></i>Выход
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>



            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbarLanguage" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="/Content/images/ru_ru.png" style="width: 22px; height: 22px;" alt="Русский">
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarLanguage">

                        <a href="/Home/Language?culture=ru-RU" class="nav-link">
                            <img src="/Content/images/ru_ru.png" style="width: 22px; height: 22px;">
                            Русский
                        </a>

                        <a href="/Home/Language?culture=en-GB" class="nav-link">
                            <img src="/Content/images/en_gb.png" style="width: 22px; height: 22px;">
                            Английский
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                //установить культуру(язык) в глобализации
                var globalizeCulture = Globalize.culture('ru-RU');
            </script>
        </div>
    </nav>
```